# TypeError: LoginPage.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'driver'

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I got this error: `FAILED test_login.py::Test_001_Login::test_Login - TypeError: LoginPage.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'driver'`
why is the driver doesn't get the value?

LoginPage.py

```
from selenium import webdriver

class LoginPage:
    textbox_username_id= "Email"
    textbox_password_id= "Password"
    button_login_xpath="//input[@class='button-1 login-button]"
    link_logout_linktext="Logout"

    def __init__(self,driver):
        self.driver = driver`
```

test_login.py

```
import pytest 
from selenium import webdriver
from pageObjects.LoginPage import LoginPage

class Test_001_Login:
    baseURL = "``https://admin-demo.nopcommerce.com/``"username = "admin@yourstore.com"
    password = "admin"

    def test_Login(self,setup):
        self.driver = setup
        self.driver.get(self.baseURL)
        self.lp = LoginPage()
        self.lp.setUserName(self.username)
        self.lp.setPassword(self.password)
        self.lp.clickLogin()
        act_title = self.driver.title
        if act_title == "Dashboard / nopCommerce administration":
            assert True
            self.driver.close()
        else:
            self.driver.save_screenshot(".\Screenshots\"+"test_Login.png")
            self.driver.close()
            assert False
```

conftest.py

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pytest

@pytest.fixture()
def setup():
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
return driver
```

Comment: You have initialize the ```'instance variable'``` as ```'driver'``` in the ```Loginpage``` class So when you call the ```LoginPage``` class inside the ```test_Login``` function of  ```Test_001_Login``` you need to give the value of  ```driver``` variable inside the ```self.lp = LoginPage()```

Answer (score 0):

`driver` is missing, because you never pass it to `LoginPage`

```py
def test_Login(self,setup):
    self.driver = setup
    self.driver.get(self.baseURL)
    self.lp = LoginPage(self.driver)
```

Comment: can you help me, how to write find_element_by_id

Comment: can you help me, how to write find_element_by_id in new version of selenium



 def setUserName(self,username):
        self.driver.find_element_by_id(self.textbox_username_id).clear()
        self.driver.find_element_by_id(self.textbox_username_id).send_keys(username)

    def setPassword(self,password):
        self.driver.find_element_by_id(self.textbox_password_id).clear()
        self.driver.find_element_by_id(self.textbox_password_id).send_keys(password)